# Does the scene with Galadriel, Saruman, Elrond and Gandalf take place in the book?

Tags: the-hobbit, an-unexpected-journey

The scene I'm referring to in *The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey* takes place in Rivendell where Galadriel, Saruman, Elrond and Gandalf discuss the dwarves' quest and the Morgul blade.

It's been a few years since I read *The Hobbit* and I'm wondering if this scene took place in the book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are referred to as the White Council in the lore of LotR. This meeting does not take place in The Hobbit but is mentioned in The Lord of the Rings Appendices which were released with The Return of the King.

This meeting is mentioned in Appendix B, at least [according to the LotR wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/White_Council)

Information about the appendices can be [found here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_Appendices).

Furthermore, I'd like to point out that Peter Jackson only has rights to make movies based on *The Hobbit* and the LotR series. So anything in these movies will only come from these 4 books.

Comment: Awesome..its been bothering me since I watched the movie

Comment: No problem. I've been meaning to look into the difference as it's been a while since I've read any of the books as well.

Comment: Well, anything in the movies occurred in that time frame.  From what I've heard, he's got access to notes and other items to be able to make these movies.  I will try to find a link about this.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. It is mentioned but not in the Hobbit. I believe it's from another book of Tolkiens though and I'll link to it if I find the reference.

Comment: If not another book, at least one of the appendices perhaps?